# Display first letter of image name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am displaying a random image from a list in a table. I want to display the first letter of the random image's name within the cell along with the image. can someone help me with that.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=Javascript>

 imagelist = ["man.gif","wolf.gif", "wall.gif"]

function ranImage() {


whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagelist.length);

document.write('<IMG SRC="' +imagelist[whichImage]+ '">');

 imagelist.splice(whichImage,1);


 }


</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="newtable"/>

 <tr>

 <td>


    <script language="Javascript"> ranImage();</script>

   </td>
     <td>

     <script language="Javascript">ranImage();</script>

     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: First letter of what? The image's name? so `m` or `w`?

Answer (score 1):

```
imagelist[whichImage].charAt(0)
```

That will get the first letter of the image, so just do whatever you want with that.

Comment: where am i supposed to use imagelist[whichImage].charAt(0). i want to display the letter before the image in the same cell.

Comment: Then just put it before the image, it's not hard.

Comment: its displaying ( imagelist[whichimage].charAt(0) with the image not the first letter

Comment: Are you putting it in the string? Look, you already have a value outside the string, it's not hard to work out how to add another one >_>

Comment: Still didnt get it. help me out

Comment: @Anez perhaps you need to go away and learn to program in Javascript before you start demanding help for a very, very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.substr` to retrieve a single character, as well as multiple characters, should the need ever arise.

```
function ranImage() {
    whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagelist.length);

    // 0 is starting position to trim from, 1 is length of 1 character
    var whichLetter = imagelist[whichImage].substr(0, 1) 
    ...
```